# Passing parameters to a Backbone View (id, className and so on)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have some code that makes a Backbone.View, based on some params I pass to it, like so:

```
// The Form View
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (opts) {
        debugger; // This is here only to figure out what gets executed first: if "id" method or "initialize"
        this.options = {};
        this.options.id = opts.id;
        this.options.className = opts.class;
    },

    id: function () {
        debugger; // The application will stop here before the debugger I set in the initialize method
        return this.options.id; // options is undefined!
    },

    className: function () {
        return this.options.className; // options is undefined!
    }
});    

// The params
var params =  
    fid: "some-form",
    class: "form-horizontal"
};

var myForm = new FormView(params);
```

But the `this.options` property is always `undefined`. As I can see, the method that sets the view's properties runs BEFORE the `initialize` method. As a workaround I think I could access the initialize method inside de id callback and call its arguments, but I'm not sure how to do this properly. And I don't think this is a good approach either.

Any ideas? - Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the opening curley brace on params, typo?

Comment: @steveax yup, I just updated the question =)

Comment: Any reason why you can't assign the `id` directly in the `initialize` method?

Comment: @Jack I tried that already. For some reason, setting the "el" properties at the initialize method (this.id = opts.id) doesn't work at all. Those properties are "undefined" as the view renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the usual way of passing options to the view? Something like:

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.foo = this.options.foo;
        this.bar = this.options.bar;
    }
});

var params = {foo: '1', bar: '2'};
var v = new FormView(params);
```

You can also pass as params `{id: '1', className: 'your-class'}` and Backbone will apply it automatically to the respective `id` and `className` properties of the target `View`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be initializing the `options` attribute properly. You should have

```
initialize: function (opts) {
    this.options = {}; // you were missing this part
    this.options.id = opts.id;
    this.options.className = opts.class;
},
```

Comment: Sry, typo of my part. In my real code there's an object initializer. I'm going to update the code.
My issue is that "id" method is actually being run before "initialize" method. So the options passed to the view were not set yet.